# How do I center the random output from my list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *
import random
from PIL import Image

movies = (open('C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Projects\movies.txt').readlines())
mymovie = (movies)
print(mymovie)

def pickMovie():
    movieLabel.configure(text=random.choice(movies))

#GUI Window
root = Tk()
root.title('Movie Randomizer')
root.geometry('900x800')

#picture
photo = PhotoImage(file='C:\Users\Sivang\Desktop\Projects\popcorn.gif')

label = Label(image=photo)
label.image = photo # this is my reference bitch
label.pack()

#Movie Label
movieLabel = Label(root, text="", font=('Times New Roman', 28))
movieLabel.pack()

#Pick Movie
pickButton = Button(text="Pick!", fg="red", bg="white", command=pickMovie)
pickButton.pack(side='bottom', padx = 5, pady = 25)

#start the GUI
root.mainloop()
```

My question refers to the following code:

```
movies = (open('C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Projects\movies.txt').readlines())
mymovie = (movies)
print(mymovie)
```

Whenever I run my program, the text isn't always in the center. My question is how do I always keep it in the center.

Comment: Easiest way is probably `movieLabel.configure(text=random.choice(movies).center(30))`.

Comment: Actually, it seems centered to me already. Can you describe your issue in more detail?

Comment: How you do keep a print statement centered? centered to what?

Comment: Did the posted answer help you or did you find your own answer?

Answer (score 1):

Using `str.format` you can specify right, left or centered alignment, see [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

Example:

```
movies = "star wars\nsome awesome movie\nanother great movie\nmeh movie"
>>> print movies
star wars
some awesome movie
another great movie
meh movie
```

Now using `.format` and specifying center aligned with a specific width we get:

```
>>> print '\n'.join('{:^50}'.format(s) for s in movies.split('\n'))
                    star wars                     
                some awesome movie                
               another great movie                
                    meh movie
```

You can add some flair:

```
>>> print '\n'.join('{:-^50}'.format(s) for s in movies.split('\n'))
--------------------star wars---------------------
----------------some awesome movie----------------
---------------another great movie----------------
--------------------meh movie---------------------
```

You'll most likely have to play around with the width to ensure your strings are centered.